# Migration from Joomla 1.0.12 to latest version

Tags: joomla

Does anyone of you have an experience in migrating a Joomla site from 1.0.12 directly to 3.x version ? If yes, any good reading you could recommend ?

An non profit association is asking me for some help, but I have never used Joomla, but I know other CMS softwares

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration also depends on the template, modules and components installed. A blank joomla should upgrade from 1.0.12 to 3, but the other stuff makes the difference

https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Upgrading_Versions

Comment: thank, appreciate you comment. I will see what is used once they find back the credentials to connect to the host....:-))

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct migration path from 1.0.12 to Joomla 3.x.

You will need to upgrade to 1.0.15, migrate to 1.5 and then migrate to 3.x.

Depending on the complexity of the website, it might be easier to build the new website and migrate the content manually.

Comment: Hello Neil, many thanks for your answer.. appreciate....that is what I understood from the various post and documentation I found. Regards
Daniel